# Dart referenced callback with a return value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to return a value on a callback in Dart. Now it's simple to do this when we use direct callbacks but I have another case, I have to use referenced callback. It might be silly but I have to do this.

**Approach 1 (not working):**

```
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  TestClass().method2(() => "Returend String");
}

class TestClass {
  String Function() getStringCallback;

  TestClass() {
    method1();
  }

  void method1() {
    TestClass2(getStringCallback);
  }

  void method2(String Function() callbackString) {
    this.getStringCallback = callbackString;
  }
}

class TestClass2 {
  String Function() getStringCallback;

  TestClass2(this.getStringCallback) {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      print(getStringCallback.call());
    });
  }
}
```

Above code causing an error because `getStringCallback` is null.

TestClass2 is being instantiated by `method1` so it's possible to do this there. Is there any possibility to do this from `method2`.

Currently, I am doing this.

**Approach 2 (working as expected):**

```
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  TestClass().method2("Returend String");
}

class TestClass {
  String getStringCallback;

  TestClass() {
    method1();
  }

  void method1() {
    TestClass2(()=>getStringCallback);
  }

  void method2(String callbackString) {
    this.getStringCallback = callbackString;
  }
}

class TestClass2 {
  String Function() getStringCallback;

  TestClass2(this.getStringCallback) {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      print(getStringCallback.call());
    });
  }
}
```

I want to do it with approach 1. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the callback with a function that can change it's behavior when a new callback is assigned. Replace `TestClass2(getStringCallback);` with `TestClass2(() => getStringCallback());`

Answer (score 0):

The Approach 1 not work because the `method1` is called before `method2`.

Following the logic on main:

When you call `TestClass()` it call the constructor of class, and in constructor of `TestClass` you call the `method1`. After you called the construct, you call `method2`, so in your logic that's happens:

```dart
main() {
  TestClass().method2(() => "Returend String");
  // ˆˆˆˆˆ Here you call construct and the constructor call method1
}

main() {
  TestClass().method2(() => "Returend String");
  //            ˆˆˆˆˆ Here you call method2 after called method1
}
```

I hope you understood with my English